# Big subfigure problem

Tags: floats, subfloats

I have a followinng code:

```
    \subsection{Grouped Test Images with their Histograms}
\subsubsection*{Portrait}
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=6cm]{einstein_image&histogram.jpg}
  \centering
  \caption{Einstein Image and Histogram}
  \label{fig:3_9_1}
  \caption*{Source: https://processing.org/tutorials/color/}
  \end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=6cm]{lena_image&histogram.jpg}
  \centering
 \caption{Lena Image and Histogram}
  \label{fig:3_9_2}
  %if there are any # $ % & ~ _ ^ \ { } in your URLs, Latex will not be nice to you. 
  %http://stack_overflow.com/~foo%20bar#link would be
  %http://stack\_overflow.com/\~foo\%20bar\#link
  \caption*{Source: http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/root\_files\_V3/image\_databases.htm}
 \end{subfigure}
 \hfill
\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=6cm]{woman_image&histogram.jpg}
  \centering
  \caption{Woman Dark Hair Image and Histogram}
  \label{fig:3_9_3}
  \caption*{Source: http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/root\_files\_V3/image\_databases.htm}
 \end{subfigure}
 \end{figure}
```

The problem is that I found my subfigures at the end of the document. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! There are inconsistent parameters in your code: three  subfigures on a same row, each textwidth wide.

Comment: Replace `\begin{subfigure}{\linewidth}` with `\begin{subfigure}{0.32\linewidth}` ...

Comment: 18cm is a tall figure. Probably there isn't room, so what else is LaTeX to do? You've requested only the figure be 'here if there's space'. Probably there isn't. LaTeX will change your requestion to `ht` to give itself a fighting chance, but 18cm is too large for most text blocks for a top placement. The figure can't go anywhere else, so it just queues until LaTeX typesets it at the end to stop you losing it altogether. This is quite sensible behaviour in response to desiderata it cannot possibly satisfy.

Comment: Also, don't use [h], which means here if possible, next \clearpage otherwise.  Use [htp] instead.